# how do put OR clause after the AND clause in laravel query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have this query

`WHERE col1 = val_11 AND (col2 = val_21 OR col2 = val_22)`

many people give the query builder for OR(AND) query, but i can't find any with AND(OR) query
how do i turn this into laravel query builder?

Answer (score 0):

You should use closure based where method:

```
$query->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('foo', 1)->orWhere('bar', 2);
});
```

This query generates sql:

```
(where foo = 1 or bar = 1)
```

And you can add other conditions after or before the statement.

Comment: if i put another ->where() after the ->orWhere(), would it count as AND clause?

Comment: No. Consider each closure as a parenthesis. If you want another AND, you should add it before of after the where closure